# How do I make a HTML slider the background of a website?

Tags: html, css, image, slider

So I have made a simple HTML and CSS website with the background image currently set as the ocean picture.

Here is the code for this website
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cooking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="title">
             <h1>Nila Palmo Ram</h1>
         </div>
        <div class="button">
         <a href="#" class="btn">ARTICLES</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn">ARTWORK</a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Century Gothic; }

header{
    background-image: url(../2.jpg); 
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
} 

ul{
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgb(115, 196, 233);
}

ul li.active a{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgb(115, 196, 233);
}

.main{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.title h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 70px;
}

.button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 62%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.btn{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgb(115, 196, 233);
}
```

For this website I want the background image to be a slider showing three images. I have built the slider separately. Here is the code for the slider:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="1.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Rustic wall decor out of reclaimed wood</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="2.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Make memorising easier with spaced repetition</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="3.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Stunning wall art using washi tape</div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();
    function showSlides() {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if(slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}
.mySlides {
  display: none
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

Could someone please tell me how I can make the slider of pictures the background of my website?
Thank you!

Comment: Try setting the pictures container as position: absolute;  z-index: -999; width:100%;height:100% to put it at the back of the page, any content on top should have a transparent background if needed

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `position:absolute` and set the container `height` and `width` to `100%`. (I used `vh` & `vw` to take the device/view height and width).

I hope you can take it forward. Cheers!!!

```js
// no change here
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  /* added */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}


/* added */
.mySlides img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- image urls changed -->
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422246654994-34520d5a0340?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Rustic wall decor out of reclaimed wood</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523706120980-3f90ca135ad6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Make memorising easier with spaced repetition</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578301978018-3005759f48f7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1928&q=80" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Stunning wall art using washi tape</div>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace your HTML code with the above code blocks. Make sure you add the css block inside style.css file.